# Found a specific stash how do I show it?

Tags: git, git-stash

With the following command I found a stash that contains a certain untracked file:

`git rev-list -g stash | xargs -n1 git ls-tree -r | sort -u | grep widget`

This command returns:

`100644 blob 05e25619a6f2649b7d635b5aa897cbfc68a4f15d   widget/app.css`

**How do I now show this stash?**

I tried:

`git stash show -p stash@{100644}`

What returned `stash@{100644} is not a valid reference`

Thank you

Comment: I think you've filtered too narrowly - that's one line from a list of files within a stash, anything to identify which stash would be in a header of some sort.

Comment: Any other command maybe I could filter with?

Comment: I think you'll need to rework your pipeline to have a loop of some sort, so you can echo out the stash identifier before running `ls-tree` and `sort`. Which makes this something of an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your actual task is to find some stash, you've tried this way and failed, so need to go back and look at the original problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is likely to be no solution given the state listed, and the original problem needs to be solved a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using this (untested):

```
git log -g stash --format='%H %gD' |
while read hash rel; do
    git ls-tree -r $hash | sed "s:^:$rel :"
done |
grep widget
```

#### Explanation

Note that:

> ```
> git rev-list -g stash | xargs -n1 git ls-tree -r | sort -u | grep widget
> ```

does not produce *quite* the output that you want.  You got:

> ```
> 100644 blob 05e25619a6f2649b7d635b5aa897cbfc68a4f15d   widget/app.css
> ```

This is one line from `git ls-tree -r` output.  The format of these output lines is *`mode type hash`*<kbd>tab</kbd>*`path`* (with a literal tab character).  The *`mode`*, in this case `100644`, is from a limited and fixed set of possibilities: `100644` means *blob that is not executable*.  (The *`type`* field is determined by the mode so it is redundant.)  The *`hash`* of a blob is the blob's hash ID: in fact, except for `160000`, which is called a `commit` and represents a *gitlink*, the hash is always some internal Git object hash within this repository.  None of these is ever a stash commit hash ID or a relative number.  That is, none of these can be given as `stash@{number}`.

If we return to the `git rev-list -g stash` command, this simply walks the stash reflog.  It is similar to running `git reflog stash`, except that instead of an output of the form:

```
<hash> stash@{0}: <subject>
<hash> stash@{1}: <subject>
  .
  .
  .
```

it produces only the hash IDs.  So the output from `git rev-list` contains the information you'd like printed.  But that output goes into `xargs -n1 git ls-tree -r`, so `xargs` eats the output and feeds it to `git ls-tree -r`, which eats it up and never prints it out again.

To get the information you want, then, you'll need to modify or replace your `xargs` command.  A modification that would allow you to reach your goal would be to print the commit hash ID and/or stash-relative name at the left of each `git ls-tree -r` line.

To get the stash-relative name, it might be wise to alter or replace the `git rev-list` output.  Unfortunately `git rev-list --format='%H %gD'`, which would be the logical way to handle this, does not work.  We must use `git log`, which has a flaw: `git log` is a *porcelain* command rather than a plumbing command, so it obeys user configurations, which may change its behavior.<sup>1</sup>  But there's nothing we can do about that here, so we might as well press on.

---

<sup>1</sup>It seems to me that `git log` needs a `--porcelain` flag a la `git status`, although I've always wondered why this flag is spelled `--porcelain` instead of `--plumbing`.

---

#### An alternative sequence

We'll start with:

```
git log -g stash --format='%H %gD'
```

and run its output through a command that will take the hash, use `git ls-tree -r` to list the entire contents of the commit whose hash is on the left, and prefix each line with the reflog-relative `%gD` output and a space.  We'll use plain `sh` programming constructs for these, though this will be a bit slow:

```
git log -g stash --format='%H %gD' |
while read hash rel; do
    git ls-tree -r $hash | sed "s:^:$rel :"
done
```

Here, we run `git ls-tree -r` on the hash and pipe its output through `sed`, the stdin-stream editor.  The editing command is to replace the beginning of the line (`^`) with the relative reference.  We can use a colon `:` character as the delimiter because we know that no colons can appear in any branch name.<sup>2</sup>  This means that expanding `$ref` will not accidentally trigger an end-of-delimiter sequence.  We use double quotes for the `sed` command argument so that `$ref` *does* get expanded, and that—plus the shell's `while read` loop construct—explains the entire loop.

We can drop the `sort -u` as there's no reason to sort these and `uniq`-ing each line seems unproductive, but we still want the final `| grep widget` to this little `git log | while` one-liner into a solution that finds stashes that contain any path string that will match `widget`, such as `stowidgetname` (Stow ID, Get Name).

---

<sup>2</sup>Colon is not the only option; see [the `git check-ref-format` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format).  However, colon is visually distinctive and non-problematic.  The usual slash delimiter is a bad choice in general because reflog names might contain slashes.  In our particular case we know that the ref name is `stash`, which does not contain a slash, but it's nice to use something that will work for other names, should we ever try to repurpose this extended one-line script.  `$rel`, being a reflog-relative expansion, will be the refname followed by `@{` followed by a series of digits followed by `}`, so `@{}` and digits and any valid ref-name character are all *bad* choices.  Control characters are bad choices in general as they are hard to see.  That leaves space, tilde, caret, and colon from rule 4 as the obvious candidates.  Caret is our beginning-of-line character so that's a bad choice, and space is visually ambiguous, so we're down to tilde and colon.  I picked the colon.

Answer (score 3):

As said in other answers : `100644` is not a commit hash, nor a stash number. The command you built actually doesn't keep track of the commit id which produces this specific `ls-tree` entry.

If you want to find what  stash(es) contain a file `widget/app.css`, try for example :

```
# if you have more than 50 stashes, replace '50' with a number big enough
for i in {0..50}; do
    if git rev-parse --verify -q stash@{$i}:widget/app.css; then
        echo "stash@{$i}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This could do with an explanation of what the commands are doing, in particular what `git rev-parse --verify -q` does, and I don't think I've ever seen an argument in the form `committish:filepath` before.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
git show 05e2561
```

The stash uses just regular git commits, like any other.

**EDIT:**

As the OP mentions in the comments, the above command only shows a blob, not a commit.

My only idea now is to do:

```
git stash list
```

to get a list of all the commit hashes in the stash.  Then for each commit hash, do:

```
git show --name-only abcd1234
```

substituting the actual commit hash.  I'm sure a shell script could be written to automate that.

But as I said in the comment, if you have tons of stash commits, and you are using the stash for long-term storage, you are doing `git` wrong.  You need to learn how to use branches, or maybe all you need to do is just commit to `master` more often.

Can I ask you, why you use `stash` instead of just `commit`?  A stash is just a commit under the covers, but disguised and made more complicated.  I use `git` constantly and *never* use `stash`.  I just make a normal commit if I need to save work and work on something else.

If you must use `stash`, it should only be for very short-term use while you save away your work to work on another task.  Your stash should almost always be empty.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I think the line shown isn't identifying a commit, it's identifying the "blob" of that particular file's state in that particular commit.

Comment: Returns: `git show 100644
fatal: ambiguous argument '100644': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
`

Comment: Why are you using such a complicated command chain?   Just use `git stash list`

Comment: I have so many stashes that I can't find it anymore

Comment: The `100644` looks like a file permission, not anything to do with `git`

Comment: Why are you using `stash` so much.  It seems like you need to be using branches instead.  Take a time out and learn `git`.   There are so many good tutorials.  I use `git` constantly and *never* use `stash`.  If you use `stash` at all, it should only be as a quick and dirty way to save work while you switch to some other task.  It is *not* for long-term use.  Your `stash` should almost always be empty.  During the limited time you use `stash` there should be no more than 1 or 2 commits on the stash.

Comment: But your totally right with `git show 05e25619a6f2649b7d635b5aa897cbfc68a4f15d` I see the file, that already helps